# How to trigger radioButton to checked if I pressed on Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-linearlayout

How can I make the radio button get selected if I pressed on other place ( not the radio button ) but on image, text view and etc inside 1 Linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_balance"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dc_white" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button_payment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
         
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the adapater: PaymentAdapter.java

```
     @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View allView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_choose_payment, parent, false);
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) allView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) allView.findViewById(R.id.card_balance);
            final RadioButton r = (RadioButton) allView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_payment);
            LinearLayout layout_card = (LinearLayout) allView.findViewById(R.id.layout_1);

            r.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
            r.setTag(position);
            r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
}
```

Right now the condition is I can pressed only at radio button.

I've already tried to add onClickListener to linear layout, and yes I can pressed on the linear layout however the Radio button not select only 1 but all selected.

this code for linearLayout onClick

```
 layout_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
                r.setTag(position);
                if (r.isChecked()) {
                    r.setChecked(true);
                    r.setSelected(true);
                } else if (!r.isChecked()) {
                    r.setChecked(false);
                    r.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Sorry for my bad explanation, any help is very grateful for me. 
Thank you

Comment: use setChecked(true) method

Comment: where should I put that method ? @hosseinAmini

Comment: how many radio buttons u have coz i see only one in your xml but in your explanation u r saying all radio buttons getting selected instead of one..

Comment: It's a dynamic radio button, I have 4 dummy data so it appear 4 radio button or 4 linear layout depends on the data. @Moulesh

Comment: @StevenTan i feel u r implementing it wrong may be u need recyclerview or list view with row item containing radio button so clicking anywer on card u can make the radio button checked

Comment: the xml I write on this page is already inside ListView already sir @Moulesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your **getView(...)**, write

```
layout_card.setTag(position);
```

and change click listener as

```
layout_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedPosition = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            notifyDataSetChange();
        }
    });
```

remove below code, if not needed

```
        r.setTag(position);
        r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: so I add this `layout_card.setTag(position);` inside getView() and outside of the listener ?

Comment: Works without any issues..Thanks